# Nativescript 2.3.0 grey images

Tags: nativescript

I've just updated the core modules to 2.3.0 on my NativeScript app and all iOS and Android images have turned grey.

Not sure why this has happened as it works fine in previous versions.

Comment: The is known bug in 2.3 and has been already reported in https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2674 . In case you have setup color property in some of the parent components,  the Images will be colored too. the fix is coming soon and as temporary solution you could add the modules in your project with @next.Follow the the steps below: 1.`tns plugin remove tns-core-modules` 2. `tns plugin add tns-core-modules@next`

Comment: That fixes it, will wait for the next release.